# Setting a Global Doctype

Tags: php, .htaccess, xslt, doctype

Is it possible using PHP *(I was thinking may the phpinfo file or a php.ini file)* or an .htaccess file to set a doctype for an entire subdirectory?

Basically, in a nutshell, I'm using a software that uses XSL templates to output data to a set of HTML files.  Modifying the **xsl:output** tag to include the doctype breaks the template and therefore, does not work.  Just adding the doctype in the XSL file, breaks it as well.

I need the proper doctypes in place for my CSS to function properly, cross-browser.  I realize that I could add the doctype to the HTML files after export but, I'm really striving to automate this process.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the `<xsl:output>` element?

```
<xsl:output
method="xml|html|text|name"
version="string"
encoding="string"
omit-xml-declaration="yes|no"
standalone="yes|no"
doctype-public="string"
doctype-system="string"
cdata-section-elements="namelist"
indent="yes|no"
media-type="string"/>
```

Note the **doctype-public="string"** and **doctype-system="string"**

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_output.asp

Comment: @Ben - What 'element' are you referring to?  Here is what I had been trying to use in my template and was not working  --- <xsl:output 
  doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
/>

Comment: @Ben - Yes, the xsl:output element is being used.  Like I said though, adding the doctype is not working.